# Is there a way to recover the two sorted halfs in a merge sort algorithm if I have the sorted array?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Suppose I have an unsorted array P and it's sorted equivalent P_Sorted. Suppose L and R refer to the left and right halves of P. Is there a way to recover L_Sorted and R_Sorted from P and P_Sorted in linear time without using extra memory?

For further clarification, during a recursive merge sort implementation L_Sorted and R_Sorted would be merged together to form P_Sorted, so I'm kinda looking to reverse the merge step.

Answer (score 0):

In a merge sort, you divide the array into two halves recursively and merge them. So at the last merge, you would have already sorted the left and right halves - they are sorted independently - that is why divide and conquer name.

Therefore when doing a merge you can just look at the sizes of the arrays to be merged and if they are equal ( even input size ) or differ by 1 ( odd input size ), you are at the last merge. Then you could store those sorted arrays in some variable before merging them.

***BUT*** if you are not allowed to mess with the function, and you need to work only with the sorted array and the original array, I think the solution is not straightforward. I found an [url](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/%7Esantoro/Reports/UnMerging.pdf) that poses this problem and a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems feasible in linear time for very specific datasets:

If there is a way to tell the original position of each data element in the sorted list, for example if these are records with a creation date and a name field and the original array is in chronological order, selecting from the sorted array the elements that fall in the first or second half can be done in a single scan in linear time with no space overhead.

In the general case, sorting the left and right half seems the most efficient way to get `L_sorted` and `R_sorted`, with or without `P_sorted`. The time complexity is **O(n.log(n))**.